# 404 while trying to generate models with swagger codgen

Tags: angular, swagger, jhipster, swagger-codegen

I am developping an application using angular in the frontend and spring boot in the backend.I am also using jhipster in both back and front.I want to generate models and services of the frontent using swagger-codgen

**./ng-swagger-gen -i http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs -o C:\Users\fm\Documents**

but i always got 404 or 407 :

**Error reading swagger location http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs: Error: Error downloading http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs
HTTP ERROR 404**

However i can acces to the url http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs via chrome and i got no problem.

Comment: Does `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` returns your JSON swagger?

Comment: yes when i open it with chrome i got the json

Comment: Just tried it on Windows and it worked for me, "ng-swagger-gen -i http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs -o testswag" generated few typescript files. Anyway if you can't get it to work, just save the JSON from Chrome to a local file and run ng-swagger-gen against it.

Comment: that 's what i did and it works